# I want to Generate documentation for my Project through Xcode..Any suggestions?

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

I am trying to generate documentation for my Xcode project and I tried Jazzy documentation and Readme.io but I would like to know about **Swagger** will work like jazzy or not If it is can i know how to install **Swagger** in my Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger is a tool for RESTful API. You better stick with Jazzy for documenting Xcode projects.